# Tweepy. TweepError: Failed to send request: local variable 'auth' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mongodb, tweepy

I'm learning how to use mongoDB, and I'm having some trouble with tweepy.

I just wanted to do a simple twitter search with this code:

```
lookup ='Notebooks' # Just a test case
api = API()

search = []
page = 1
tweets = api.search(lookup,page = page)
```

But I get this error.

```
TweepError: Failed to send request: local variable 'auth' referenced before assignment
```

I have no idea what that means. Any suggestions? I've tried updating, but that has not worked either.

Comment: We probably need to see more of your code...and a full traceback.

Comment: Thats actually all of it.

Comment: but there is nowhere `auth` in your given code ? Are you sure it is full code snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not the right way of doing the things. As per the [documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/code_snippet.html#oauth), You need to create an api object and pass it as a parameter to the `tweepy.API(auth)` method and to create an `auth` object you will need 4 things: consumer token, consumer key , access token and access secret key. which can be retrieved form the [twitter app manager](https://apps.twitter.com/)

A basic sample login code may look something like this:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```